# save mathod return false for GenericDao

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a method that find object by Id from database

```
ClassA obj = getDao().find(id);
```

and then I update my object `obj.setName("newName");`

after that I save my object `getDao().save(obj);`

in method save of generic DAO firstly it verify if session contain the object to return false

```
/**
     * <p>
     * If an entity already exists in the datastore with the same id, call
     * _update and return false (not new). If no such entity exists in the
     * datastore, call _save() and return true (new)
     * 
     * @return <code>true</code> if _save(); <code>false</code> if _update().
     */
    protected boolean _saveOrUpdateIsNew(Object entity) {
        if (entity == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("attempt to saveOrUpdate with null entity");

        Serializable id = getMetadataUtil().getId(entity);
        if (getSession().contains(entity))
            return false;

        if (id == null || (new Long(0)).equals(id) || !_exists(entity)) {
            _save(entity);
            return true;
        } else {
            _update(entity);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I need to remove my obj from sesison hibernate or if there is a workaround to avoid this problem.

because my method return false; and any object saved.

UPDAT

I verified this condition `return false`

```
if (id == null || (new Long(0)).equals(id) || !_exists(entity)) {
            _save(entity);
            return true;
        }
```

id have a correct value id= 522

Answer (score 0):

If you want to duplicate your entity, you have to first detach it from session, set the id to null and then persist it.

Comment: save method or update can save also children of object ?

Comment: The new entity will have the same references fo children object as the old one.

Comment: sorry but I create a new object and add it to a list